# std::function to C-style function pointer

Tags: c++, function, lambda, callback, stl

I'm using a library written in C. This library accepts callbacks like this:

```c
int(*)(int arg, void* user_param)
```

Is it possible to create a `std::function<int(int, void*)>` and pass it to this library as a callback?

I know that `std::function` has a `target` method which returns the address of the stored function, but as far as I know it can't return the address if its holding a lambda expression. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Lambdas with captures cannot be cast to function types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lambda functions with C-style function pointers, just not using `std::function`.

Lambdas that don't have any capture are convertible to a functions pointer:

```
using callback_t = int(*)(int arg, void* user_param);
void set_c_callback(callback_t, void* user_param);

// ...

void foo() {
    set_c_callback([](int a, void* data) {
        // code
    }, nullptr);
}
```

But there is also a way with lambda with captures, using `std::any`:

```
// The storage can be inside a class instead of a global
std::any lambda_storage;

template<typename T>
void foo(T lambda) {
    lambda_storage = lambda;
    set_c_callback([](int n, void* user_data) {
        auto& lambda = *std::any_cast<T>(static_cast<std::any*>(user_data));
        lambda(n);
    }, &lambda_storage)
}

// ...

foo([k = 1](int n) {
    std::cout << n + k << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: That 2nd lambda still doesn't use captures. It's the equivalent of a free function using a global variable.

Comment: @Darhuuk yes. But you can have that `std::any` in the storage of a class.

Comment: That way it's not a global, it is simply attached to the class instance.

Comment: True, that's a nice way to add a layer of indirection around the capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a lambda to the C library, you should be able to, as long as the lambda has no captures. A captureless lambda can be implicitly converted to a function pointer, so simply setting it as a callback should work.

Passing a lambda that uses captures (or e.g. an `std::function`) will not work, since they can't be converted to "plain" function pointers, because they hold an internal state.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function` cannot be used where a C-style function pointer is expected.

A *non-capturing* lambda can (but a *capturing* lambda cannot).